# HTTPS Requests with ClientResource

Tags: java, restlet

When I create requests for `http` it works with this:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(protocol + "://localhost:" + port + path);
```

However when I create `https`requests I get that error:

```
Starting the internal [HTTPS/1.1] server on port 8081
Starting the internal HTTP client
A recoverable error was detected (1001), attempting again in 2000 ms.
A recoverable error was detected (1001), attempting again in 2000 ms.
Stopping the internal server
```

I know that when we use `Client` object we should set that:

```
Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTPS);
```

So, I am suspicious about setting something like that for `ClientResource`.  I tried that but didn't solve:

```
resource.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
```

Also tried that:

```
Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTPS);
resource.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
resource.setNext(client);
```

However I got the same logs. As you can see from logs, it first creates an HTTPS server but HTTP client.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related to certificates. I've set a trust keystore and used it for my example.